# Send POST request using postman but receiving GET request in php. I try to create API using postman

Tags: php, postman

```
echo $req=$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]; // outputs "GET"
```

I try to create API using postman. When run this in localhost it's run perfectly but when run this code in a server then it's show me GET. can anyone help me?

Comment: What it shows when you run it depends on what kind of request you sent when you requested it. localhost vs server makes no difference to that. It won't lie to you. Double-check your assumptions about what you sent

Comment: I'd bet your HTTP request is being redirected to HTTPS. This'll convert a POST to a GET.

Answer (score 4):

Check your server http or https. If server is https
And you send http post request then it show this kind of problem.